# python 2.7 and 3.3 subprocess module difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.3

I have the following code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.kill()
p.wait()
print(p.stdin.write(b'some'))
```

and I ran it with python 2.7 and python 3.3. With python 2.7 an exception is thrown when I try to write to stdin. With python 3.3 this code prints 4. What is the difference between python 2.7 subprocess module and python 3.3?

Comment: Docs for both [2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) and [3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) warn to use `communicate` rather than `.stdin.write` - does that make any difference?

Comment: It would be nice to know which expression is thrown in Python 2.7 :-)

Comment: The exception is `IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. When I use `communicate` exception is not thrown, but I need to use `stdin.write`.

Comment: Why are you trying to first kill the process and then write to it's stdin? To me it seems that this is just undefined behaviour.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? To handle gracefully a situation where the child process died? On which platform? Do you get an exception on 3.3 if you add `p.stdin.flush()` in the end?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to handle a situation where the child process died. Platform is Linux. Yes, I get an exception if I add `p.stdin.flush()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in the default value for `bufsize`. It is `0` (unbuffered) in Python 2.7 therefore `write` causes `EPIPE` error. Pipes are fully buffered in Python 3.2+ i.e., until you flush the buffer, no error is detected. From [`subprocess`' docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess#popen-constructor):

> Changed in version 3.3.1: `bufsize` now defaults to `-1` to enable
>   buffering by default to match the behavior that most code expects. In
>   versions prior to Python 3.2.4 and 3.3.1 it incorrectly defaulted to `0`
>   which was unbuffered and allowed short reads. This was unintentional
>   and did not match the behavior of Python 2 as most code expected.